# Dashboard software to display a categorical questionnaire which runs separate R scripts?

Tags: r, powerbi, rstudio, dashboard, business-intelligence

I'm currently a user of Power BI and R. I'm trying to create a workflow that allows for convenient data analysis all through a GUI. I desire to find a feature that allows the user to create new datasets by filling out a user friendly form like questionnaire within the dashboard GUI it self.

So for example, it asks the user what they want to name the dataset and what tasks they want the dataset to execute through preset R scripts, so like auto web scraping, filtered formatting, ect. Which then all comes back to the dashboard software for fast visualisation. Basically a place to run specific R scripts through selectable drop down menu questionnaires and text boxes to define titles and other variables.

While Power BI allows the user to run R scripts, I haven't found the above task to be possible in Power BI, where the user can run scripts through GUI selection. Is there any dashboard software out there that allows for this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into [Shiny for R](https://shiny.rstudio.com/). This is R Studio's product for developing interactive web apps. I've been using Shiny for a couple of months now and find it pretty easy and intuitive to build decently complex apps. I believe everything you mentioned could be built into the Shiny's app backend. You can manipulate the GUI using HTML, CSS, and even Javascript if you wanted precise control over your app.

Comment: Oh sweet, i'll take a look into it. Thanks!